# How to get data from sub documents

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Hi i am new to MongoDB in general but experienced in java.

I am now trying to get data from my MongoDB through an java application but i am having trouble retrieving data from sub documents, and was hoping  to get som help with understanding how it works and how to do it.

**EDIT**

Test code that gives me the team name.

```
BasicDBObject queryTeam = new BasicDBObject("team", team);
FindIterable<Document> foundTeam = db.getCollection("teams").find(queryTeam);      
MongoCursor<Document>     cursor = foundTeam.iterator();

while(cursor.hasNext())
{
    Document tmp = cursor.next();
    return tmp.get("team").toString();
}
```

I am interested of getting the information of who hired a specefic player in the team. The players are in a sub document and have some attributes, (see imgur link).
I am interested of getting the attribute hiredBy and my question for you is how do i do that in java?

Structure of the collection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzG1k.jpg

Tips for you guys for creating a collection layout easy: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

**SOLUTION**

```
 DistinctIterable<Document> players = db.getCollection("teams").distinct("Players", Document.class);
```

Returns all the players and i can look trough them in java and see who created them.

Moderator can mark this question as solved. Solution to the problem is above.

Comment: Here is the example of how the structure works: http://imgur.com/a/r8hom, I am using this site to create it: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. My goal is to find who hired the players. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: can you add the code that you are trying to the post ?

Comment: Do you want to know who hired a player whose firstName is "X"?

Comment: I have removed the jdbc tag, because your question has nothing to do with the JDBC API.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with sub document? Could you post an example of the structure of your collection and document?

Edit: for some reason I can't add a comment on your post. So, consider this answer a comment for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question/comments and the structure given, check this,

```
db.collectionName.findOne({"players.firstName":"Bengt"},{"players.hiredBy":1})
```

PS: Will edit when there is a change in the question.